# Difference Between Property and Observer?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Why would a computed property in a component not recognize a dependency changed within a view, but does recognize the change as an observer?

I tried two different approaches. The first one, a computed property that depended on the outside variable (`projectId`), only recognized the change some of the time. The other, an observer, sometimes recognized the change around the same time as the computed property, but also recognized it when the computed property did not. For example, it recognized both the property and observer when it inserted the element, only recognized the observer on a page transition within the same route, and only recognized the property on a page transition to a different route. Why is that? From what I understand, a dependency set on a computed property is similar to an observer, so why would it have trouble?

This is the component using the computed property:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  isFavorite: function() {
    console.log("property");
    // returns true or false
  }.property("favorites", "projectId")
});
```

This is the component with an observer:

```
import Ember from "ember";

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  isFavorite: null,

  observesFavorite: function() {
    console.log("observer");
    // sets isFavorite to true or false
  }.observes("favorites", "projectId")
});
```

Why do these two work differently? How would I be able to get the component to recognize the changes to `favoriteId` all of the time?

**Edit**

To clarify, the component worked with only a computed property when it was only present on the projects index page:

```
// app/templates/projects/index.hbs
<table>
  {{#each sortedContent}}
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">{{favorite-star action="updateFavorites" projectIdBinding="id" favoritesBinding="userFavorites"}}</td>
      <td>{{name}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</table>
```

However, it stopped working when I added it to the project show page:

```
// app/templates/project/index.hbs
{{favorite-star action="updateFavorites" projectIdBinding="id" favoritesBinding="userFavorites"}} {{name}}
```

That was when I tried using the observer instead of the computed property to set the `isFavorite` property. However, when I tried that, it stopped working on the projects index page. Now, it only works when I have *both* the observer and the computed property, which I know is the incorrect way of creating this.

The only code I have for the component is in the `app/components` folder. It doesn't have a template in `app/templates/components`, and it worked just fine until I had to add it to the show template as well.

Why would this happen? Why would the computed property only work on projects index, and the observer only work on project show?

**Edit Again**

I've created two JSBins showing the issue. They're messy, but they work for this purpose. [This](http://jsbin.com/vopubovuxi/1/edit?html,css,js,output) is an example of it using a computed property to update the component and favorites array. It works normally on the index page, but breaks when the user tries to favorite or unfavorite it on the show pages. [This](http://jsbin.com/diniwotufe/1/edit) is it using an observer, and works okay on the show pages, but not on the index.

Comment: Could you construct a JS Bin that demonstrates this problem?

Comment: Sorry if I missed this, but are you actually _using_ the computed property? Computed properties aren't activated unless you call `get()` or use it in a template. That could be your problem.

Comment: The computed property is used to bind the class name of the component. I hadn't included it in my code example, but at the top of the component I have `classNameBindings: ['isFavorite:fa-star:fa-star-o']`. I'm trying to create a JSBin example, but it's difficult to replicate a large Ember CLI app in JSBin.

Comment: You shouldn’t have to replicate a large application. A minimal example of computed properties vs observers would help demonstrate what you mean. As it is, it seems like there must be something happening that you don’t mention here, because in my experience, they work exactly as described.

Comment: I've elaborated on the issue in my question. I'm getting the feeling that the JSBin example isn't going to display it properly, since there are some major differences between building an example from scratch versus using Ember CLI.

Comment: Are you listening to the right property? Maybe you should be listening to favorites.@each or favorites.length? I can't tell from the code if favorites might be an array.

Comment: That doesn't work. Favorites is an array, but I noticed during my debugging that it wasn't listening properly to projectId.

Comment: This is far from elegant, but I've made a JSBin that shows where the code breaks down when using the computed property: http://jsbin.com/vopubovuxi/1/edit. I know this is super messy, but I wanted to get an example out that shows the issue. Basically, it works fine when you're on the favorites index, but it breaks down if you try to change it on an individual favorite, then use the quickmenu ("Favorite favorites") to view another favorite.